# Gorm freeze while connect to mysql on AWS (no errors)

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, grails-orm

this code stacks on aws,  but locally works fine, no errors

```
func Connect() {

dsn := fmt.Sprintf(
    "%s:%s@tcp(%s:3306)/%s?charset=utf8&parseTime=True&loc=Local",
    os.Getenv("DB_USER"),
    os.Getenv("DB_PASSWORD"),
    os.Getenv("DB_HOST"),
    os.Getenv("DB_NAME"),
)
log.Println("db 1") 
DB, err = gorm.Open(mysql.Open(dsn), &gorm.Config{})
log.Println("db 2")
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err.Error())
    panic("CAN NOT CONNECT TO DB")
}
```

}
db -1 appears in logs
db -2 absent
and after some time  aws kills container

Comment: So, have you verified (by other means) that an attempt to establish a TCP connection to `$DB_HOST:3306` actually succeeds? I mean, "freezes" when trying to do something related to networking typically occurs due to network packets being dropped so that the networking code waits for various timeouts.

Comment: Does "gorm" allow setting a connection timeout? If yes, and you set it to something low like, say, 5s, does `gorm.Open` fails with an error?

Comment: db host is correct

Comment: You almost certainly have a firewall / networking issue here that has nothing to do with the code.

Comment: Whether the host is correct or not was not the question; the question was: are you able to make a TCP connection to that host+port combo using any method except the Go MySQL driver, and whether it succeeds or not. This is merely a classic approach to solving engineering problems: you perform an experiment to divide the problem space into the two halves: network/stack problems and driver problems, and remove one of these halves in the end.

Comment: same issue, no error and hangs forever, using Gorm and mysql